# ServiceStack /types/csharp generating invalid attribute signatures in v5.7

Tags: servicestack

In our upgrade to ServiceStack v5.7, the file generated by the NativeTypesService at `/types/csharp` is now producing invalid code.  We are using ASP.Net (NOT Core), .Net Framework 4.7.2.

Specifically, the `References` and `StringLength` attributes are generated with named parameters, resulting in the errors when included in a client project (using the same version of ServiceStack):

```
error CS1729: 'StringLengthAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'type' of 'ReferencesAttribute.ReferencesAttribute(Type)'
```

I've checked the [blame history](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blame/d70fe3b0ac8b0afc26feef24b1a10ce9340e5702/src/ServiceStack/NativeTypes/CSharp/CSharpGenerator.cs#L432-L471) of the relevant bit of the `CSharpGenerator`, but nothing has changed in years.  I'm at a loss.

**How can we generate valid code using the `/types/csharp` NativeTypesService endpoint?**

---

I've created a minimal sample project below to illustrate this.  All ServiceStack libraries are v5.7 (Text, Interfaces, etc.).  When we downgrade only the core `ServiceStack` to v5.6, the expected output is generated.

**v5.6 Signature**

```
namespace TestTypes
{

[Route("/Child")]
public partial class Child
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [References(typeof(TestTypes.Parent))]
    public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
}

[Route("/Parent")]
public partial class Parent
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

}

**v5.7 Signature**

```
namespace TestTypes
{

[Route("/Child")]
public partial class Child
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [References(Type=typeof(TestTypes.Parent))]
    public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
}

[Route("/Parent")]
public partial class Parent
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(MaximumLength=100)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Sample project**

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("Test", typeof(MyService).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container) { }
}

public class MyService : Service
{
    public object Get(Parent request) { return null; }
    public object Get(Child request) { return null; }
}

[Route("/Parent")]
public class Parent
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Route("/Child")]
public class Child
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Parent))]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think this is just broken behavior in 5.7.  Looking at [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/64b05c460cdb8e3cf1bdd03675263f5b54e3dafa#diff-b7581e8e2004e474fa96ef834ba389d5) it has since been fixed.  I guess we'll downgrade to 5.6 and wait for 5.7.1 or 5.8.

Comment: Can you retry with the [v5.7.1 pre-release packages on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#redownloading-myget-packages)?

Comment: I pulled latest from master and it worked.  I also like how exported references now have the whole name space!  Unfortunately, can't use MyGet for our CI/CD, but good to know a fix is pending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue should now be resolved with the latest [v5.8 Release of ServiceStack](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.8).